# help translating art seals

Tags: translation

[image]I recently received a painting that I am curious about who the artist is. These are the name seals in the lower left hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you need to provide a clearer image. Even a higher resolution one would do. I can't see much from this:

[image]

> ＸＸ
>
> Ｘ天
>
> 家浧
>
> Ｘ國